# HubConnection SignalR error: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: blazor-server-side, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a Net 5 Blazor server app published on a productive server and used a **valid certificate** for https requests, which works fine. Newly I added a HubConnection class to support SignalR notifications between web pages.

```
        try
    {
        string sHubUrl = NavManager.BaseUri;
        sHubUrl = sHubUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/call";

        LogBuilder.LogInfo($"URL in Call.NotificationInit: " + sHubUrl);

        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl(sHubUrl, options => {
            options.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            options.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = (msg) =>
            {
                if (msg is HttpClientHandler clientHandler)
                {
                    // bypass SSL certificate
                    clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback +=
                    (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
                }

                return msg;
            };
        })
        .WithAutomaticReconnect()
        .Build();
        hubConnection.On<string, string>("NewMessage", ReceivedNotification);

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogBuilder.LogExecption($"Exception at Call.NotificationInit", new DalException(ex, string.Format("Main module, sMA: {0}", sMA)));
    }
```

But if I call the web page through an public URL like https://crm.example.com/call, I get the following error, although the same page works fine if I call it through an internal URL like https://10.12.0.151/call:

Exception: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)

I don't know why it happens. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

After two month, I see no answer to my question, I think that more deatils about it can be useful to understanding the issue.

The following two detail logs show information about https://10.12.0.151 and https://crm.example.com respectively:

[image: Internal URL without error]

[image: Pubic URL including error]

Comment: When you use public url to access the project, Is there any valid certificate in request header? You can compare public URL and internal to see if there is any difference in request header.

Comment: Thanks @XinranShen. Yes by public url, there is a valid certificate in request header but in internal url there isn't any.

Comment: The 401 Unauthorized Error is an HTTP status code error that represented the request sent by the client to the server that lacks valid authentication credentials, So i think you need to check the credentials.